# How to optimize receiving a POST file with PHP and putting it in S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have the following scenario: a lot of image files are posted (http POST) to a php script. The script then makes some settings in the database (this is fast) and then saves the image file to an S3 bucket.

To scale this up, I believe all the loading of the  image in memory is limiting how many images my script can receive at the same time.

Question: is this so? If so, how can I limit the damage, perhaps avoiding loading that image into memory? (I don't need to do anything with it, just post it to S3 and make a note in a database).

Answer (score 0):

[This PHP S3 library](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) loads the file directly from disk. If you pass it the filename from the $_FILES array, it reads the file from disk straight to S3 without caching. I modified the code to throw exceptions in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can have users upload from your webpage directly into S3 using [Browser-Based HTTP POST](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html).

Alternatively, there are several toolkits for PHP + S3 that support streaming from the web server's file system into S3 without loading it all into memory at once. Personally, I use the [official SDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) to do it.